# Using result from the first request and passing in the second request- POSTMAN

Tags: api, postman

I want to use the result which is "id" and use it in the second request POST

[image]

Saving it as environmental variable in the first request(under tests)

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id", jsonData.token);
```

Here is the second request looks like, not sure what I am doing wrong here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is correct.
As long as you set an environment variable, you may USE this environment. From your print screen I see "no environment" on the top right corner.
I suggest either you create an environment where to save your environment variables and then use it or you use a global variable, postman.setGlobalVariable("id", ...) instead

Alex